# Problem similar to folland chapter 2 problem 51.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $(X\mathcal M,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal N,v)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.
>
> 1. If $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is $\mathcal M$-measurable, $g:Y\to\Bbb R$ is $\mathcal N$-measurable, and $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$, prove that $h$ is $\mathcal M\otimes \mathcal N$-measurable.
> 2. If $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $g\in L^1(v)$, prove that $h\in L^1(\mu\times v)$ and $$\int\, h\,d(\mu\times v)=\left[\int\,f\,\mathrm d\mu\right]\left[\int\,g\,\mathrm dv\right].$$

Could someone show me how to prove this. I have been staring at it, and cannot even think where to start. I am a bit desperate here. I will highly rate for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. If anyone has comments, I would greatly appreciate them.

$\text{a)}$ Define $\phi:X\times Y\to\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ by $\phi(x,y)=\left(f(x),g(y)\right)$ and define $\psi:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $\psi(m,n)=mn$. Notice that $h$ is the composition of these two functions, i.e., $$h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)=\left(\psi\circ\phi\right)(x,y).$$
Since a continuous function of a measurable function is measurable, it suffices to show that $\phi(x,y)$ is a $(\mathcal M\otimes\mathcal N)$-measurable function from $X\times Y$ into $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$. Let $R$ be an open rectangle in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ such that $R=A\times B$ for some open sets $A$ and $B$ in $\Bbb R$. Then $$\begin{align}
\phi^{-1}(R)=\phi^{-1}(A\times B)&=\{(x,y):f(x)\in A,g(y)\in B\}\\\,\\
&=\{(x,y):f(x)\in A\}\cap\{(x,y):g(y)\in B\}\\\,\\
&=\left(f^{-1}(A)\times Y\right)\cap\left(X\times g^{-1}(B)\right)\\\,\\
&=f^{-1}(A)\times g^{-1}(B).
\end{align}$$Since $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal M$ and $g^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal N$, and $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ measurable, respectively. Thus, $\phi^{-1}(R)\in\mathcal M\otimes\mathcal N$, and thus, $h(x,y)$ is $(\mathcal M\otimes\mathcal N)$-measurable. $\,\blacksquare$

$\text{b)}$ Let us suppose $f$ and $g$ are non-negative measurable functions. Let $\{\phi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ be sequences of increasing functions such that $\phi_n\to f$ and $\psi_n\to g$ converge pointwise on $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Then $\{\phi_n\psi_n\}$ is an increasing sequence such that $\phi_n\psi_n\to h$. By the monotone convergence theorem, we have $$\begin{align}
\int\,fgd(\mu\times v)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\,\phi_n\psi_nd(\mu\times v)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int\phi_nd\mu\int\psi_ndv\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\phi_nd\mu\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\psi_ndv\right)\\
&=\int\,fd\mu\int\,gdv.
\end{align}$$$\quad$Since $|fg|=|f||g|$ and $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$ and $g\in L^{1}(v)$, then $fg=h\in L^{1}(\mu\times v)$. Also, since $f$ and $g$ are real valued, $$\begin{align}
\int\,fgd(\mu\times v)&=\int(fg)^+d(\mu\times v)-\int(fg)^-d(\mu\times v)\\
&=\int f^+g^+d(\mu\times v)+\int f^{-}g^-d(\mu\times v)-\int f^+g^-d(\mu\times v)-\int f^-g^+d(\mu\times v)\\
&=\left(\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu\right)\int g^+ dv-\left(\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu\right)\int g^-dv\\
&= \left(\int f^+d\mu -\int f^- d\mu\right)\left(\int g^+d\nu -\int g^- d\nu\right)\\
&=\int fd\mu\int gdv. \qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you use paste the latex code here instead of using an image?

Comment: @Abramo Did you give me the -1? How rude! The reason why I did not paste the latex code is because I have various commands set up on my latex documents, and I would have to go through the code and change various parts so that it will show up on stackexchange. Why do you need the code? The math is sufficient, no?

Comment: I think it would be ridiculous to give someone -1 just because it's posted as an image rather than latex code… +1 to cancel the downvote!

Comment: @Abramo I LaTeXified his image, now someone must check if there are any errors. +1 by the way to the answer by Sarah.

Comment: $f(x)g(y)\in\mathbb{R}$ not in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: I'm confuse in part that $(fg)^+-(fg)^-$ becomes $f^+g^++f^-g^--f^+g^--f^-g^+$. I was searching for properties of positive and negative parts of functions and find nothing. To me is really confuse...

Comment: @Mathecm $fg$ is positive when either both $f$, $g$ are positive or when they're both negative.

Answer (score 7):

1. The problem is easy if $f$ and $g$ are characteristic functions of measurable sets. Then we use the fact that we can approximate pointwise a measurable functions by linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets.
2. We assume first that $f$ and $g$ are non-negative. We use the definition of the product measure when $f=\chi_A$ and $g=\chi_B$. Then we extend to simple functions and use monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

@Sarah, here is my proof..... which I think is a little pretty because I don't use sequences.

Let $F(x,y):= f(x) \forall y \in Y$, $G(x,y):=g(y) \forall x\in X$.
Then $$F^{-1}([-\infty, a))=\{(x,y) \in X\times Y : F(x,y)\in [-\infty,a)\}$$
$$=\{(x,y) \in X\times Y : f(x)\in [-\infty,a), \forall y\in Y\}$$
$$=\{x \in X : f(x)\in [-\infty,a) \}\times Y\in \mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N}$$ as $Y\in \mathcal{N}$ and $\{x \in X : f(x)\in [-\infty,a) \}\in \mathcal{M}$ as $f$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable; similarly, we can do this for $g$.

By Tonelli's theorem we have $|F(x,y)G(x,y)|=|f(x)g(y)|=|h|:X\times Y \to [0,\infty]$ that $|h|$ is integrable because it is measurable (product of measurable functions is measurable and absolute value of measurable function is measurable) and nonnegative.  On the other hand, $|h|$ is integralbe if and only if $h$ is integrable (hence $h$ is integrable).

now by Fubini's theorem,because $h$ is integrable and $f$ and $g$ are measurable we have

$$\int_{X\times Y} h d(\mu \times \nu) = \int_X (\int_Y f(x) g(y) d\nu (y) ) d\mu (x) = (\int_X f d\mu )(\int_Y g d\nu )$$