# Product measures and $\sigma-$ finite measures

Tags: measure-theory, product-space

[Problem similar to folland chapter 2 problem 51.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592197/problem-similar-to-folland-chapter-2-problem-51)

The actual problem in Folland mentions that $X,Y$ are not necessarily $\sigma-$finite. Then how can I use Fubini-Tonelli theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $L^1$ function vanishes outside of a $\sigma$-finite set $M_f$ (use $\{x\mid f(x)|\geq 1/n\}$).

Then apply Fubini on the set $M_f \times M_g$ only.

Comment: Ok so if $E_n=\{x:|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, then $M_f= \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Then how can I show that $\mu(E_n)<\infty$ for all $n$?

Comment: We have $\chi_{E_n}/n \leq |f|$ (why?). Now integrate this inequality.